# Proxy Issue ENOTFOUND Create-React-App Http-Proxy-Middleware Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app, http-proxy-middleware

I've run into a new problem when proxy my client requests from CRA to my express API server when in development.

I get the following error message from HPM. And I can see it returns as 504 Gateway Timeout

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/game/leaderboard from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000 (ENOTFOUND) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

I'm using the setupProxy.js as follows:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = app => {
    console.log('from setupPrxoy.js');
    app.use(
        '/api/**',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'http://localhost:5000',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

That seems to be working fine as I get the following when I start the React dev server:

```
[HPM] Proxy created: /  -> http://localhost:5000
```

This is my server app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
    credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

//ROUTES
require('./routes/currentGame')(app);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on ${PORT}`);
});
```

And that routes file:

```
const db = require('../models');
module.exports = app => {
  app.get('/api/game/leaderboard', async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            await db.Entry.find({
        gameNumber: 2
      })
                .limit(50)
                .populate('user', 'username')
                .sort({ totalScore: 'descending' })
                .exec((err, entries) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return next(err);
                    } else {
                        const leaderboard = [];
                        entries.forEach(entry => {
                            let newObj = {
                                totalScore: entry.totalScore,
                username: entry.user.username
                            };
              leaderboard.push(newObj);
                        });
            return res.status(200).json(leaderboard);
                    }
                });
        } catch (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
  });
}
```

The API works fine in the client, it returns the JSON as expected.

I've tried rolling back to older versions of React, React-Dom, React-Scripts and HPM but no luck.

I've tried removing the HPM and using a simple proxy in the package.json on the client side. Didn't work, got a similar message.

So I know the proxy is working (I think)

I've looked up ENOTFOUND and worked out it is some sort of DNS Address Error.

This is what I get when I in the command line

```
node      5033   [mynamewithheld]   23u  IPv4 0x93d5c87aa7d4fbd3      0t0    TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
node      5035   [mynamewithheld]   23u  IPv6 0x93d5c87aa770a0ab      0t0    TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
```

I'm wondering if I need to do something with the Header Requests on the server or if the Ports are running differently?

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I think I have narrowed the issue down to hardware.

It doesnt work on 2011 iMac running OS Sierra 10.12.6 which was I was using but tested on 2015 MacBook Air running OS Mojave 10.14.16 and it works.

Beyond knowing that is the issue, any idea how to fix so it works on the iMac?

Comment: I totally agree, I've been following // posting [my experience here](https://github.com/netlify/create-react-app-lambda/issues/19). I've gotten the issue immediately after 3 restarts today directly after updating macOS Monterey 12.4 (21F79).. Keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

Make sure localhost is mapped to 127.0.0.1 in your etc/hosts file.